# Why DbContext is diposing every time?

Tags: entity-framework, wcf, design-patterns, castle-windsor

I am implementing UOW and Generic repository pattern  using Entity framework 6 and castle windsor. I am following the link [http://blog.longle.net/2013/05/11/genericizing-the-unit-of-work-pattern-repository-pattern-with-entity-framework-in-mvc/][1]

My code is given  below :

**Conceptu.Core:**

DataContext:

```
public interface IDataContext : IDisposable
    {
       IDbSet<TEntity> Set<TEntity>() where TEntity : class;
       int SaveChanges();
    }
```

Domain:

```
public interface IUnitOfWork : IDisposable
    {
        void Dispose();
        void Save();
        void Dispose(bool disposing);
        IRepository<TEntity> Repository<TEntity>() where TEntity : class;

    }


public interface IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
    {

        TEntity Find(params object[] keyValues);
        int Insert(TEntity entity);
        IQueryable<TEntity> Queryable();
        IRepository<T> GetRepository<T>() where T : class;

    }
```

I am Implementing all these interfaces in Conceptu.Data Layer:

**Conceptu.Data**

EFUnitOFWork:

```
public class EFUnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
    {
        #region Private variable

        private readonly IDataContext _dataContext;
        private bool _disposed;
        private Dictionary<string, object> _repositories;
        private ObjectContext _objectContext;
        private DbTransaction _transaction;

        #endregion Private variable

        public EFUnitOfWork(IDataContext context)
        {
            _dataContext = context;
        }

        public EFUnitOfWork()
        {
            _dataContext = new ConceptuModelContainer();
        }

     public void Save()
    {
      if (_disposed)
          throw new ObjectDisposedException("UnitOfWork");
      _dataContext.SaveChanges();
    }
        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (_objectContext != null && _objectContext.Connection.State ==                         ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                _objectContext.Connection.Close();
            }

            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }



        public void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (_disposed) return;
            if (disposing) _dataContext.Dispose();
            _disposed = true;
        }

        public IRepository<TEntity> Repository<TEntity>() where TEntity : class
        {

            if (_repositories == null)
            {
                _repositories = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            }

            var type = typeof(TEntity).Name;

            if (_repositories.ContainsKey(type))
            {
                return (IRepository<TEntity>)_repositories[type];
            }

            var repositoryType = typeof(Repository<>);
            try
            {
                _repositories.Add(type, Activator.CreateInstance(repositoryType.MakeGenericType(typeof(TEntity)), _dataContext, this));
            }
            catch (Exception er)
            {
                throw er;
            }
            return (IRepository<TEntity>)_repositories[type];


        }



    }
}
```

Repository.cs:

```
public class Repository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
    {

        #region Private Fields
        private readonly IDataContext _dbContext;
        private readonly IDbSet<TEntity> _dbSet;
        private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
        #endregion Private Fields

        public Repository(IDataContext context, IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
        {
            _dbContext = context;
            _dbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();
            _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;



        }
      public virtual int Insert(TEntity entity)
        {
            try
            {
                  _dbSet.Add(entity);
                return _dbContext.SaveChanges();
            }


            catch (Exception er)
            {

                var error = er.InnerException.InnerException as Exception;
                throw error;
            }


        }





        public IQueryable<TEntity> Queryable() { return _dbSet; }


        public IRepository<T> GetRepository<T>() where T : class
        {
            return _unitOfWork.Repository<T>();
        }

        internal IQueryable<TEntity> Select(
          Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
          Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null,
          List<Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>> includes = null,
          int? page = null,
          int? pageSize = null)
        {
            IQueryable<TEntity> query = _dbSet;

            if (includes != null)
            {
                query = includes.Aggregate(query, (current, include) => current.Include(include));
            }
            if (orderBy != null)
            {
                query = orderBy(query);
            }
            if (filter != null)
            {
                query = query.AsExpandable().Where(filter);
            }
            if (page != null && pageSize != null)
            {
                query = query.Skip((page.Value - 1) * pageSize.Value).Take(pageSize.Value);
            }
            return query;
        }
    }
```

BootStrapper.cs

```
public class Bootstrapper
    {

       public static void Initialise()
       {
           IWindsorContainer _container = new WindsorContainer();
           _container.Kernel.Register(Component.For<IDataContext>().ImplementedBy<ConceptuModelContainer>());
           _container.Kernel.Register(Component.For<IUnitOfWork>().ImplementedBy<EFUnitOfWork>());
           //IoC.Container.Register(typeof(IDataContext), typeof(ConceptuModelContainer));
           //IoC.Container.Register(typeof(IUnitOfWork), typeof(EFUnitOfWork));


       }
    }
```

Service Layer: I am calling it from wcf layer

I am calling repository from Service layer

```
public class CompanyService : ICompanyService
    {
        #region Private fields
        private readonly IRepository<Company> _companyRepository;

        #endregion

        #region Constructor

        public CompanyService(IRepository<Company> companyRepository)
        {
            _companyRepository = companyRepository;
        }
       _companyRepository.Insert(_objcompany);

    }



[ServiceContract]
    public interface ICompanyService
    {
          [OperationContract]
         int SaveCompany(CompanyRequest _objCompanyRequest);
    }
```

In Global.asax.cs I have written for registering

IWindsorContainer _container;

```
    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        _container = new WindsorContainer();
        _container.AddFacility<WcfFacility>().Register(

            Component.For<IDataContext>().ImplementedBy<ConceptuModelContainer>().LifestylePerWebRequest(),
            Component.For<IUnitOfWork>().ImplementedBy<EFUnitOfWork>().LifestylePerWebRequest(),
            Component.For(typeof(IRepository<>)).ImplementedBy(typeof(Repository<>)).LifestylePerWebRequest(),

            Component.For<ICompanyService>().ImplementedBy<CompanyService>      ().Named("Conceptu.Services.CompanyService.CompanyService")
            );

    }
```

But My problem Is when I am calling Save using wcf service the  error is throwing. The error shows DBContext is disposed.

Comment: pls post only codes that are relevant to your question. no one will read all of this stuff

Comment: For good understanding I have given all the code bcoz I am Unable to understand where it is going wrong

Comment: @Joydip I understand that but it makes the question unsuitable for Stack Overflow. This is not a code review site. Questions are expected to be concise and answerable in a reasonable amount of time.

Comment: Ok I try to miminimize the code

Comment: You show two different places where you register your IDataContext and IUnitOfWork with a Windsor container. Only the one in your Application Start shows a LifestylePerWebRequest configuration. Why do you have both a bootstrapper and application start?

Comment: Sorry Actually I have removed that code.But giving the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Component.For<IUnitOfWork>().ImplementedBy<EFUnitOfWork>().LifestylePerWebRequest()
```

- You dispose your context on every request via the Unit Of Work because you have registered it in IoC to be like that even thou you do not explicitly disposing it in UoW. In order to prove that you can place a break point inside the dispose and see the call stack if Castle is calling the Dispose.
- You bring the context through a factory to the UoW. A better approach is to store the compiled model in a cache so that you do not generate the model for the contex on every request.

Here is an example implementation of a model store which you can modify for your needs :

```
public class DefaultDbModelStore : IDbModelStore
{
    private readonly IDbModelBuilder _modelBuilder;
    private readonly Dictionary<string, IDbModel> _modelsDict;

    public DefaultDbModelStore(IDbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        _modelBuilder = modelBuilder;
        _modelsDict = new Dictionary<string, IDbModel>();
    }

    public IDbModel GetModel(string moduleName)
    {
        if (moduleName == null) { 
            moduleName = string.Empty; 
        }
        //TODO: Try using ReaderWriterLockSlim for improved performance
        lock (_modelsDict)
        {
            IDbModel result;
            if (!_modelsDict.TryGetValue(moduleName, out result))
            {
                result = _modelBuilder.BuildModel(moduleName);
                _modelsDict.Add(moduleName, result);
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

There is a constructor of DbContext which takes the compiled model.

Comment: Thanks For your suggestion.Could please give the solution how to put context in cache.

Comment: Sorry. This was a mistake. It is the compiled model that is cached and not the context itself. The most that I can think of for a dbContext is to make it scoped or per web request. You can see how compile the DbModel and cache it [here](http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2012/04/21/code-first-building-blocks/). Caching the dbCompiled model of a large object model will save you a lot of time because it is compiled every time.

Comment: @Joydip You can explore further the possibility of level 2 caching [here](http://www.roelvanlisdonk.nl/?p=2827) if you need even more performance.